# Aura component error : Document.body.append is not function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

Please help and suggest new to aura components, how to write document.body.append in aura components.
I have one components which loads from static resources and i'm calling method from static resources where one line is document.body.append which is not a function

```
 const newContent = document.CreateElement('config');

  document.body.append(newContent);
```

also i could see only **[object HTMLBodyElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }** How to resolve the issue.

```
<div class='container'  style="background-color: #fff !important">   
          <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Sample}" /> 
        <ui:button press="{!c.btn}">Click</ui:button>
     </div>
```

in Sample.js file

```
 window.loadInitialMethod = function() {
    const newNode = document.createElement("New-Class");
    document.append.body(newNode);
    }
```

in controller

```
({
    btn: function(component, event, helper) {
        loadInitialMethod ();
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084972/append-is-not-a-function-error-in-console

Comment: @TusharJadav Its not working i tried

Comment: Can you please add the component code so I can look at it?

Comment: @TusharJadav i have pasted my code. Please have alook. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `appendChild()` method instead of the append.

**`appendChild()` method:**
The appendChild() method of the Node interface adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.

Documentation: [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

I have used your code and done some modifications and it appends the element into the body element.

CMP HTML:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <div class='container'  style="background-color: #fff !important">   
        <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Sample}" /> 
        <ui:button press="{!c.btn}">Click</ui:button>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

CMP JS:

```
({
    btn: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("Called..Js");
        loadInitialMethod();
    }
})
```

Sample.js(Static Resource):

```
window.loadInitialMethod = function() {
    console.log("Called external JS");
    const newNode = document.createElement("div");
    newNode.innerHTML = "Test Div";
    console.log("New Element=>"+newNode);
    document.body.append(newNode);  
    console.log("New Element Append=>"+document.body.childNodes);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Console Log:
[image]

PS:
Output with New-Class Element:
[image]

Comment: THanks for the reply . but my component is not loaded .

Comment: Have you updated your code according to the above code which I have provided?

Comment: yes but  New-Class nothing is loaded.

Comment: When i have use this JS it is working.
`window.loadInitialMethod = function() {
    console.log("Called external JS");
    const newNode = document.createElement("New-Class");
    newNode.innerHTML = "Test Div";
    console.log("New Element=>"+newNode);
    document.body.appendChild(newNode);  
    console.log("New Element Append=>"+document.body.childNodes);
} `

Comment: Make sure you are using the `appendChild` method not an `append` method. I have added the new screenshot of the **New-Class** Element.

Comment: content is loaded but mine webpage needs to be loaded. using New-Class is separate react.js component